# Error on Joomla 3.3 update

Tags: joomla-3.x, upgrade, update

I am trying to upgrade my Joomla from 3.3.6 to 3.4.1. Whenever I press the update now button I get the following error:

```
0  Cannot open file for writing log
```

I tried the following:

1. I created a php file to output the absolute path and added /tmp and /logs to my path to temp and path to log variables.
2. I changed the permission for the logs and tmp folders and the configuration.php file and they are now readable and writable.

However , I am still getting this error message every time I try to update. Is there anything I need to edit further ?

Comment: Could you try following the first steps in my answer here? http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/4674/168

Comment: So in the "System" tab in the Global Configuration, all directories and files listed are writable?

Comment: I did try all of them , I even tried updating through the Extension Manager then Install from URL , however this throws the following error:

` -1 Copy file failed`

Comment: Yes under System information -> Directory permissions all are writable.

Comment: If everything else fails you can also upgrade by unzipping the contents of the upgrade package inside your Joomla directory, overwriting existing files. That might or might not solve your problem, but at least you'd be up to date.

Comment: @johanpw - I would only suggest this if no database changes are made in the update script

Comment: I actually tried the overwriting existing files suggestion since I ran out of options and it worked. I am facing other problems now with my website tabs that I'll try to fix. Thank you both for your help

Comment: I am experincing the same problem. Iy is curious that: 1. using ftp I changed the permisissions to file directory "logs" and also to "tmp". Despite of this they appear as "protected" in the "sysm informataios" in Joomla. 2, a have an old vertion of the site ina durectory I create: ND NAMED AS OLDIES" and the version there is does not show this type of problem. Depit the old version refers to the same "logs" and "tmp" folders, although they do not appear as protected in sysm ingformation of the old site. Than you if you could help me.;